# How can menu items be displayed from bottom up using CSS

Tags: css, css-float

I have my menu working the way I want with the exception that menu elements are displayed from the top down as supposed to bottom up. I tried changing the CSS properties, but still can't get it working. I need my DIV container to be align on the bottom of the parent container. I used 'bottom: 0' CSS property but that doesn't have any affect using both 'position: absolute' and 'position: relative'.

How can I align all the elements within the parent DIV be displayed at bottom: 0 (bottom up)?

Then click on the **Projects** bottom link (refresh if you need to reset the menu items). I need that same behaviour I already have, just the menu items should start from the bottom up and be aligned all the way to the bottom.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Partizan

Comment: For a start, each submenu should be *inside* the relevant `#nav li`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to accomplish this is to either put the divs inside the sought after parent element. Ergo the `<li>` you want to associate these links with. Give the parent `<li>` a style of `position:relative`. The on hover set the `position` of the child `div` or `li` to `abosulte` and `left:0;top:0;`. Then from there you can style it closer or farther with `margin`.

Comment: Thanks Robbie, playing around with your suggestion got me closer to the behaviour I was looking for! 

Also, thanks thirtydot and Basic for your suggestions that I accommodated in my solution as well! :)

cheers,
partizan

Answer (score 0):

Try using padding-top to push them down with an id or class on each sub menu.

Then if that fails, try using min-height: auto; on each parent.